# Algorithm that involves rounding and multiples

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, rounding

So I have a problem where I have an array of some length (usually long). I have an initial start index into that array and a skip value. So, if I have this:

```
var initial = 5;
var skip = 10;
```

Then I'd iterate over my array with indexes 5, 15, 25, 35, etc.
But then I may get a new start value and I need to find the closest value to the initial plus or minus a multiple of the skip and then start my skip. So if my new value is 23 then I'd iterate 25, 35, 45, etc.

The algorithm I have for this is:

```
index = (round((start - initial) / skip) * skip) + initial
```

And then I need a check to see if index has dropped below zero:

```
while(index < 0) index += skip;
```

So my first question is if there's a name for this? A multiple with random start?
My second question is if there's a better way? I don't think what I have is terribly complicated but if I'm missing something I'd like to know about it.

If it matters I'm using javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: So the new value you might get is not in relation to either skip nor initial, right? And this value can be negative?

Comment: @AlfonsoGarnett: The new value would be in the range of the array's indexes, so it shouldn't be negative, but you're right, it would have no relation to either skip nor initial.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*Edit*

Instead of

```
while(index < 0) index += skip;
```

if we assume that both *initial* and *skip* are positive you can use:

```
if (index < 0) index = initial % skip;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm not sure just setting to 0 would work.  What if my initial is 10 and my skip is 7?  Depending on the new value I may get something like -11.  But I can't just turn that into 0 as it needs to be a multiple of the skip.  So it would need to be 3.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: After your edit, thanks!, this seems correct.  I don't think it could ever be more than two skips less than zero, so mine would do two tests and an assignment and yours would do just one test and an assignment, so better by at least one statement!  And for what I'm doing every statement saved is useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No `while` loop required:

```
function newNum(newstart, initial, skip) { 
   var xLow = newstart + Math.abs(newstart - initial) % skip;
   var xHi = newstart + skip;
   var result = (xLow + xHi) / 2 > newstart ? xLow : xHi;
   if (result < 0) result += skip;
   return result;
}
```

Take the distance between your new starting point and your initial value, and find out what the remainder would be if you marched towards that initial value (Modulus gives us that).  Then you just need to find out if the closest spot is before or after the starting point (I did this be comparing the midpoint of the low and high values to the starting point).

Test:

```
newNum(1, 20, 7) = 6
newNum(-1, 20, 7) = 6
newNum(180, 10, 3) = 182
```

(Even though you stated in your comments that the range of the new starting point is within the array bounds, notice that it doesn't really matter).

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well, but given your 3 tests, I would expect the results to be: 6, 6, and 181. So, again, the initial and the skip set up all the possible results.  So if you have initial of 20 and skip of 7 then the possible results are 20, 27, 34, 41, etc and going the other way 20, 13, 6.

Comment: Ah... Yeah, I didn't catch that.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: The only change that was necessary was to swap which point the modulus is added to.  I'm hoping that you see that this class of problems uses the modulus and not a while loop.  The problem you've stated feels very much like a homework problem, so if it is, I'd hope that's the takeaway.

Comment: I hope that didn't come off rude.  It wasn't intended that way.  :-)  Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

To get the closest multiple of a `number` to a `test number`: See if the `modulo` of your `test number` is greater than `number/2` and if so, return `number - modulo`:

```
function closestMultiple(multipleTest,number)
{
    var modulo = multipleTest%number;
    if(0 == modulo )
    {
        return multipleTest;
    }
    else
    {
        var halfNumber = number/2;

        if(modulo >= halfNumber)
        {
            return multipleTest + (number-modulo);
        }
        else
        {
            return multipleTest - modulo;
        }
    }
}
```

To check if a number is a multiple of another then compare their modulo to 0:

```
function isMultiple(multipleTest,number)
{
    return 0 == multipleTest%number;
}
```

You might want to add some validations for 0 in case you expect any inside closestMultiple.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `index` computed as you put it

```
index = round((start - initial)/skip) * skip + initial
```

is indeed the one that minimizes the distance between the sequence with general term

a<sub>j</sub> = `j * skip + initial`

and `start`.

Therefore, `index` can only be negative if `start` lies to the left of

(a<sub>-1</sub> + a<sub>0</sub>)/2 = `initial - skip/2`

in other words, if

```
start < initial - skip/2.
```

So, only in that case you have to redefine `index` to `0`. In pseudo code:

```
IF (start < (initial - skip/2))
    index = 0
ELSE
    index = round((start - initial)/skip) * skip + initial
```

Alternatively, you could do

```
index = round((start - initial)/skip) * skip + initial
IF index < 0 THEN index = 0
```

which is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the information; I'll look closer at that what you've written.  However, I don't believe I can just set the index to 0.  As I said in another comment: What if my initial is 10 and my skip is 7? Depending on the new value I may get something like -11. But I can't just turn that into 0 as it needs to be a multiple of the skip. So it would need to be 3.

Comment: It looks like there is a confusion with the meaning of `index`. Index is the integer number of times you have to `skip` when starting from `initial`. The closest point you get is not `index` is `start + index * skip` (a<sub>index</sub> in my notation.)